# nodejs .env variable is not updating its value

Tags: node.js, api

I am making an API in node js in which I have to update the token which I have put in the .env file, but the problem is that its value is not updating.

code is something like this:

.env file

```
token = "abcd"
```

nodejs file

```
require("dotenv").config();

api.post().then((res)=>{
process.env["token"] = res.data.token;
});
```

Comment: This question doesn't contain enough information to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you need to restart your server every time you made a change to .env file. because .env file is loaded first time only and that is when server is started
And also you should use it this way to get env value

```
process.env.token
```

Comment: and also modify your env file like; TOKEN=your_value_without_qoutes

Comment: actually, I am using the token just after updating the .env file for another API call, could u just elaborate on what does restarting the server means wouldn't that start the whole program again and we will be in the same situation

Comment: I don't think that is possible because `.env file`  is the configuration file that contains the environment variables. so to update the `.env file` you need to restart the server. Out of curiosity I don't understand why you want to store token inside a `.env file`